# Save actions on previous ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, storyboard

I have my main screen with only one button on it "Show next screen". When the second screen(VC) pops up it has 2 buttons (go back and toSelect button).

My goal is to when I show my second screen and select a button on it then go back to first. The button on my second screen will stay selected. How can I do that?

So basically I need to save my actions on the second screen so if I go back to it it will show everything I did.

What is the best way to do it?

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGNCN.jpg)

Comment: Have you heard of Userdefaults.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve this using **Delegate and protocol**.

you should listen and save the changes of SecondViewController at FirstViewController using delegate methods.

And when you are presenting the secondViewController you will share the saved changes to secondViewController so that button can be selected on behalf of that information

Code -

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    
    //secondViewController States
    private var isButtonSelected = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func gotoSecondVCAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        guard let secondVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController else { return }
        secondVC.isButtonSelected = isButtonSelected
        secondVC.delegate = self
        self.present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}

extension FirstViewController: ButtonSelectionProtocol {
    func button(isSelected: Bool) {
        isButtonSelected = isSelected
    }
}
```

and for secondViewController

```
protocol ButtonSelectionProtocol {
    func button(isSelected:Bool)
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var isButtonSelected : Bool = false
    var delegate:ButtonSelectionProtocol?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var selectButton: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if isButtonSelected {
            selectButton.tintColor = .red
            selectButton.setTitle("Selected", for: .normal)
        }else{
            selectButton.tintColor = .green
            selectButton.setTitle("Select Me", for: .normal)
        }
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func gobackAction(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func selectAction(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        isButtonSelected.toggle()
        delegate?.button(isSelected: isButtonSelected)
    }
}
```

Comment: In Swift *The easiest way to achieve this using **callback closure*** or even the [`presentingController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621430-presentingviewcontroller) property. Objective-C inherited protocol/delegate is more cumbersome.